# Cropping of image in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app which uses different effects to be applied on an image.

I want to crop my image using dragging and resizing by user touch.

for now I am using `manipulation delta event` but not getting the desired results .

any suggestion how to achieve this feature or any sample code or examples...

thanks in advance..

Comment: What you tried? post your code

Comment: Add you current implementation here.. or provide some samples you tried, like a zipped project or something. Otherwise how we suggest a solution

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago i wrote an article about using Nokia Imaging SDK to edit images, and on the simple demo app i teach how to crop an image (selecting the crop región with manipulationdelta, manipulation started and manipulationended...

Originally the article was written in spanish, but [here](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=es&to=en&a=http://geeks.ms/blogs/jyeray/archive/2013/07/21/windows-phone-8-nokia-imaging-sdk-2-editando-im-225-genes.aspx) you have the automatic translation with bing translator.

The Example app code can be downloaded at the end of the article and the code is write with comments in english...

Hope This can help you.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using two overlaid images (one semi-transparent) in xaml, with cropping of the foreground image.

There is a complete code sample and explanation on my blog post here:

http://lachlankeown.blogspot.co.nz/2014/03/image-crop-page-for-silverlight-or.html